# Why does the hover code not working in here even though I put everything?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Hello I am working with php file (html) coding using jquery.
I looked up how to fix hover code problem already but seems like none of them are working for me

I used hover, pointer-events, everything but still not working.

```css
#onebox {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#onebox:hover {
  fill: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <body>

    <svg version="1.1" id="jaebal" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="959px" 
    height="593px" viewBox="0 0 959 593" enable-background="new 0 0 959 593" 
    xml:space="preserve">

    <g id="gr1234">
        <rect id="onebox" class="st0" x="359" y="24" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="242" height="166"/>
    </g>
    
    <body>
```

Is there anyone who can please check what is wrong with this code?

Comment: you never close off your `<style>` tag ..

Comment: @treyBake oops it was cut out while I was shortening my whole code. Still not working..

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/w8evs97m/  Have a go at recreating your issue, ideally here in a snippet.  Also have a read of [mcve].

Comment: Snippet seems to work? must be something you haven't copied over

Comment: @Pete snippet was an edit to make it work, but used the same original code as the working jsfiddle above.

Comment: Is it appropriate to put the ID inside the SVG tag? It was my understanding that, when using inline SVG, that the SVG tag itself gets the ID you are trying to use? Or can you manipulate elements within the SVG as well?

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you so much for your all help!! I found out the problem was the code I didn't upload in here :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pete yeah it was!! Gosh thank you